# How to create a redistributable widget using React

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I want to build a widget using React that can be consumed by non-spa sites by pointing to a js file and adding a javascript snippet. E.g.

```
<script src="somepath/mycomponent.min.js"></script>
<script>MyComponent.render('id-of-a-div')</script>
```

I have created a component with React and setup webpack. I most spa-cases the top-level component ends with

```
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.getElementById(id));
```

My component won't be able to do this since it doesn't know to which element to render itself.

How and where should I create the function that would attach the component to an element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a file with the methods that initialize and interacts with the parent page.

Maybe in utilities.js

```
 export const utilities = {
   // Here you will initialize the widget and you could pass an argument 
  // with the id of the tag where you wanna inject the app 

   initWidget: ( elementId ) => {
    if( !elementId ){
     document.createElement( 'rootApp' ); 
     ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.getElementById('rootApp'));
    }
    else {
     ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent/>, document.getElementById(id));
     }
   },
 }
```

And the utility will work in the tag of html to initilize it right there after all the js is loaded:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/widget.js'></script>
<script>
 utilities.initWidget( 'myCustomId' );
</script>
```

Maybe a flow like this could be useful to you.

Comment: Ive just remember that in webpack you can use in the output something like so it could be more customizable: **output.library, and output.libraryTarget ** https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary